# My site fails verification pagespeed (ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)

Tags: pagespeed

My site https://www.megarion.ru/ is being tested by google pagespeed. It produces the following error: Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Не удалось загрузить страницу. Убедитесь, что URL введен правильно и сервер отвечает на все запросы. Подробнее: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED.

Comment: From my point of view the question should go to russian [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that your site does not have a valid SSL certificate.

The latest version of Lighthouse (the engine behind Page Speed Insights) has a problem with this and throws an error as it sees there is a certificate at the server IP address but fails to reconcile the fact that the certificate is not for your site and crashes.

Update your certificate to include your `.com` and it should then work fine (as the redirect I believe is where the issue is occurring).